# Element is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.J2eeSessionScope

Tags: coldfusion

I have code that uses precisionEvaluate() on a session variable, but when I call the function, there is this error :

> Element emp_nextid_ANE_801 is undefined in a Java object of type class
>   coldfusion.runtime.J2eeSessionScope.

In the code, there is a condition to check this session variable with structKeyExists(), but it still shows an error. Does anyone know why it still errors?

Here is some of the code :

```
if( structKeyExists(session,'emp_nextid_#app().getCurrentAgentID()#_#officeID#') 
   AND  val(session['emp_nextid_#app().getCurrentAgentID()#_#officeID#']) GT 0) {

    var nextID = precisionEvaluate(session['emp_nextid_#app().getCurrentAgentID()#_#officeID#']);
    var qData = new Query();
    var sql = "SELECT 1 FROM Employee
               WHERE pers_id = :nextid";
    qData.addParam(name="nextid", value=nextID, cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIGINT");
    var result = qData.execute(sql=sql).getResult();
}
```

Comment: can you provide the session dump screenshot please?

Comment: <cfset temp = {}>
<cfset temp.fakeID_100_officeID120 = 100 >

<cffunction name="getID" access="public">
    <cfset tempID = 100>
    <cfreturn tempID>
</cffunction>
<cffunction name="getOfficeID" access="public">
    <cfset tempOfficeID = 'officeID120'>
    <cfreturn tempOfficeID>
</cffunction>
<cfset id = temp['fakeID_#getID()#_#getOfficeID()#']>
<cfdump var="#id#" /><cfabort />   Plz run this?

Comment: (Edit) Yes, start by dumping the session scope (and the value of `emp_nextid_#app().getCurrentAgentID()#_#officeID#`) to verify that A) the dynamic variable name is actually correct B) a variable with that name really does exist. Given the dynamic reference, it is possible the reference is off / incorrect somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call, app().getCurrentAgentID(), might be generating values that are changing dynamically. In any case, you can improve the code snippet to:

```
var key = 'emp_nextid_' & app().getCurrentAgentID() & '_' & officeID;
if( structKeyExists(session,key) AND val(session[key]) GT 0) {

    var nextID = precisionEvaluate(session[key]);
    ...
    etc.
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.. now i tried to using this code and so far it's good.. :)